# How do I query sysobjects with linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

What is the LINQ equivalent to the following SQL statement? I'm using entity framework 5, database first.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM SysObjects 
WHERE xtype='U' AND Name LIKE 'D[_]%' 
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with LINQ, but only if you map SysObjects to your class, otherwise this would not be possible any other way.

For example:

```
public class SysObject
{
    public int SomeUniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping file would be like this (I am using Code First approach as you did not state how you are using EF)

```
public class SysObjectMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SysObject>
{
    HasKey(p => p.SomeUniqueId);

    Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();

    ToTable("SysObjects"); // If there is Schema pass it as a 2nd argument
    Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("name");
}
```

You will need to register this mapping in your context class. Of course, if you are using Database First approach the above might confuse you as the generated code by the Visual Studio would significantly differ.

UPDATE: In case of Database-First approach, I am sure that you would be able to see system tables. Of course, you can always open the generated EDMX and implementation class and add the mapping yourself. Another approach would be to create a View which wraps around SysObjects. Then use model designer to add View.

Comment: My bad, it's database first.